# "ScrollView can host only one direct child" even with a single linear layout child

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm following the "developping android apps" course in Udacity and when I run the app (sunshine app for wheather) in a handset emulator, when I click on an item from the forecast list, it must show the details of the selected item, but the app crashes and it show the following error: "ScrollView can host only one direct child" you can see that my scrollview has only one child

here are the codes of the mainactivity, detailactivity, and the fragments:
(I removed importations)

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements          ForecastFragment.Callback{

private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private final String FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG = "FFTAG";
private static final String DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG = "DFTAG";

private String mLocation;
boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLocation = Utility.getPreferredLocation(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (findViewById(R.id.weather_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the large-screen layouts
        // (res/layout-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the activity should be
        // in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.weather_detail_container, new DetailFragment(), DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }
    } else {
        mTwoPane = false;
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);





}






@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String location = Utility.getPreferredLocation( this );
    // update the location in our second pane using the fragment manager
    if (location != null && !location.equals(mLocation)) {
        ForecastFragment ff = (ForecastFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_forecast);
        if ( null != ff ) {
            ff.onLocationChanged();
        }
        DetailFragment df = (DetailFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG);
        if ( null != df ) {
            df.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        mLocation = location;
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(Uri contentUri) {

    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(DetailFragment.DETAIL_URI, contentUri);

        DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.weather_detail_container, fragment, DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class)
                .setData(contentUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
}
```

ForecastFragment

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final int FORECAST_LOADER = 0;
// For the forecast view we're showing only a small subset of the stored data.
// Specify the columns we need.
private static final String[] FORECAST_COLUMNS = {
        // In this case the id needs to be fully qualified with a table name, since
        // the content provider joins the location & weather tables in the background
        // (both have an _id column)
        // On the one hand, that's annoying.  On the other, you can search the weather table
        // using the location set by the user, which is only in the Location table.
        // So the convenience is worth it.
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry._ID,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP,
        WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING,
        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID,
        WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT,
        WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG
};

// These indices are tied to FORECAST_COLUMNS.  If FORECAST_COLUMNS changes, these
// must change.
static final int COL_WEATHER_ID = 0;
static final int COL_WEATHER_DATE = 1;
static final int COL_WEATHER_DESC = 2;
static final int COL_WEATHER_MAX_TEMP = 3;
static final int COL_WEATHER_MIN_TEMP = 4;
static final int COL_LOCATION_SETTING = 5;
static final int COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID = 6;
static final int COL_COORD_LAT = 7;
static final int COL_COORD_LONG = 8;

private ForecastAdapter mForecastAdapter;

public interface Callback {
    /**
     * DetailFragmentCallback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(Uri dateUri);
}


public ForecastFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        updateWeather();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // The CursorAdapter will take data from our cursor and populate the ListView.
    mForecastAdapter = new ForecastAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    // We'll call our MainActivity
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // CursorAdapter returns a cursor at the correct position for getItem(), or null
            // if it cannot seek to that position.
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (cursor != null) {
                String locationSetting = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
                ((Callback) getActivity())
                        .onItemSelected(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithDate(
                                locationSetting, cursor.getLong(COL_WEATHER_DATE)
                        ));
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

// since we read the location when we create the loader, all we need to do is restart things
void onLocationChanged( ) {
    updateWeather();
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
}

private void updateWeather() {
    FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask(getActivity());
    String location = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
    weatherTask.execute(location);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    String locationSetting = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());

    // Sort order:  Ascending, by date.
    String sortOrder = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC";
    Uri weatherForLocationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(
            locationSetting, System.currentTimeMillis());

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            weatherForLocationUri,
            FORECAST_COLUMNS,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.bassem.sunshine.app.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.bassem.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ForecastFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        style="@style/ForecastListStyle"
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

DetailActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putParcelable(DetailFragment.DETAIL_URI, getIntent().getData());

            DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.weather_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

DetailFragment

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    static final String DETAIL_URI = "URI";

    private static final String FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG = " #SunshineApp";

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    private String mForecast;
    private Uri mUri;

    private static final int DETAIL_LOADER = 0;

    private static final String[] DETAIL_COLUMNS = {
            WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + WeatherEntry._ID,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_HUMIDITY,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_PRESSURE,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WIND_SPEED,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DEGREES,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID,
            // This works because the WeatherProvider returns location data joined with
            // weather data, even though they're stored in two different tables.
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING
    };

    // These indices are tied to DETAIL_COLUMNS.  If DETAIL_COLUMNS changes, these
    // must change.
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_ID = 0;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_DATE = 1;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_DESC = 2;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_MAX_TEMP = 3;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_MIN_TEMP = 4;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_HUMIDITY = 5;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_PRESSURE = 6;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_WIND_SPEED = 7;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_DEGREES = 8;
    public static final int COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID = 9;

    private ImageView mIconView;
    private TextView mFriendlyDateView;
    private TextView mDateView;
    private TextView mDescriptionView;
    private TextView mHighTempView;
    private TextView mLowTempView;
    private TextView mHumidityView;
    private TextView mWindView;
    private TextView mPressureView;

    public DetailFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null) {
            mUri = arguments.getParcelable(DetailFragment.DETAIL_URI);
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        mIconView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_icon);
        mDateView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_date_textview);
        mFriendlyDateView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_day_textview);
        mDescriptionView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_forecast_textview);
        mHighTempView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_high_textview);
        mLowTempView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_low_textview);
        mHumidityView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_humidity_textview);
        mWindView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_wind_textview);
        mPressureView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_pressure_textview);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragment, menu);

        // Retrieve the share menu item
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

        // Get the provider and hold onto it to set/change the share intent.
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

        // If onLoadFinished happens before this, we can go ahead and set the share intent now.
        if (mForecast != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
        }
    }

    private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mForecast + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
        return shareIntent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(DETAIL_LOADER, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    void onLocationChanged( String newLocation ) {
        // replace the uri, since the location has changed
        Uri uri = mUri;
        if (null != uri) {
            long date = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.getDateFromUri(uri);
            Uri updatedUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithDate(newLocation, date);
            mUri = updatedUri;
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(DETAIL_LOADER, null, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if ( null != mUri ) {
            // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
            // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
            return new CursorLoader(
                    getActivity(),
                    mUri,
                    DETAIL_COLUMNS,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if (data != null && data.moveToFirst()) {
            // Read weather condition ID from cursor
            int weatherId = data.getInt(COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID);
            // Use placeholder Image
            mIconView.setImageResource(Utility.getArtResourceForWeatherCondition(weatherId));

            // Read date from cursor and update views for day of week and date
            long date = data.getLong(COL_WEATHER_DATE);
            String friendlyDateText = Utility.getDayName(getActivity(), date);
            String dateText = Utility.getFormattedMonthDay(getActivity(), date);
            mFriendlyDateView.setText(friendlyDateText);
            mDateView.setText(dateText);

            // Read description from cursor and update view
            String description = data.getString(COL_WEATHER_DESC);
            mDescriptionView.setText(description);

            // Read high temperature from cursor and update view
            boolean isMetric = Utility.isMetric(getActivity());

            double high = data.getDouble(COL_WEATHER_MAX_TEMP);
            String highString = Utility.formatTemperature(getActivity(), high, isMetric);
            mHighTempView.setText(highString);

            // Read low temperature from cursor and update view
            double low = data.getDouble(COL_WEATHER_MIN_TEMP);
            String lowString = Utility.formatTemperature(getActivity(), low, isMetric);
            mLowTempView.setText(lowString);

            // Read humidity from cursor and update view
            float humidity = data.getFloat(COL_WEATHER_HUMIDITY);
            mHumidityView.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.format_humidity, humidity));

            // Read wind speed and direction from cursor and update view
            float windSpeedStr = data.getFloat(COL_WEATHER_WIND_SPEED);
            float windDirStr = data.getFloat(COL_WEATHER_DEGREES);
            mWindView.setText(Utility.getFormattedWind(getActivity(), windSpeedStr, windDirStr));

            // Read pressure from cursor and update view
            float pressure = data.getFloat(COL_WEATHER_PRESSURE);
            mPressureView.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.format_pressure, pressure));

            mForecast = String.format("%s - %s - %s/%s", dateText, description, high, low);

            if (mShareActionProvider != null) {                   mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) { }
}
```

activity_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.bassem.sunshine.app.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_detail" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_detail.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/weather_detail_container"
android:name="com.example.bassem.sunshine.app.DetailFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
```

fragment_detail.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_day_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_date_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_high_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_low_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_forecast_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_humidity_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_wind_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_pressure_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please review [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Probably an error when generating R. Try cleaning then rebuild. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest copying the whole fragment_detail.xml and create a new xml file to paste it there. Delete the old one of course, then clean and rebuild.

Comment: I did exactly like you said but the same error occured

Comment: Still occurs? To be clear, you have to copy the whole content of fragment_detail.